# Haskell map functions and lambda expressions

Tags: haskell, lambda, haskell-platform

I've got this expression in Haskell, now I don't understand exactly how this is applied. Typing in j returns [2,3,4]

```
j :: [Int]
j = map (\a -> a 1) (map (\a x -> x + a) [1,2,3])
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you understand about this, and what part is confusing you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two maps here, let us first analyze the subexpression:

```
map (\a x -> x + a) [1,2,3]
```

We can write the lambda expression in a form that is probably better for the above case:

```
map (\a -> (\x -> x + a)) [1,2,3]
```

So this is a function that takes a parameter `a` and returns a function. So it will return a function that takes a parameter `x` that maps to `x + a`. Thus that means that the second `map` produces a *list of functions*. Indeed, so the above expression is equivalent to:

```
[(+1), (+2), (+3)]
```

or more verbose:

```
[\x -> x+1, \x -> x+2, \x -> x+3]
```

here the `x`s in the lambda expressions are different variables.

Now the first map takes these functions, and maps these on calling the function with value one, so, this expression:

```
map (\a -> a 1) [(+1), (+2), (+3)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[(+1) 1, (+2) 1, (+3) 1]
```

and thus equivalent to:

```
[2,3,4]
```

as you found out.

We can syntactically simplify this function to:

```
j :: Num a => [a]
j = map ($ 1) (map (+) [1,2,3])
```

which is semantically equivalent to:

```
j :: Num a => [a]
j = map (+1) [1,2,3]
```

and hence:

```
j :: Num a => [a]
j = [2,3,4]
```

Comment: thanks for the explicit answer, still one tiny question, if I might ask. why does x+a result in (+a), what's the x and where did it go?

Comment: @SvenKuffer: this is more simplified notation. This is called "*operator section*" iirc: https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator  so behind the curtains, it is still `\x -> x+a`, but this would result in our list in a lot of lambda expressions.